# Refresh table data every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I am in the design stage at the moment and was wondering how I would update a table every 5 seconds.

My table will display read-only data returned from my model.

Normally my view would just have `<table></table>` HTML and then a foreach loop to write out the data.

However because I want to refresh this whole table every 5 seconds I am unsure how to implement it.

I know there is the javascript setinterval function but I'm also unsure what to do at that point.  Would it be something like this?

eg/

```
function getdata()
{
    $.getJSON("/mycontroller/mymethod"), 

                 function(data) {

                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var row = {  item.ID, item.Date,
                         item.Title
                    };
               $(#table).tableInsertRows(row);
                });

            });
}
    setInterval( "getdata", 5000 );
```

Comment: Good point! It may contain enough to have pager controls in it ie/<< < Previous Next > >>

Comment: Would that much data really change every 5 seconds or will only some of it change?

Comment: Yes, its hooking into a production environment

Comment: There's a [Data Linking](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx) something or other that Microsoft created that may be useful to you.  However, if there's is **so** much data that it would need paging, and it refreshes every 5 seconds, will a user be able to read/understand it before it's refreshed from under them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to have your `mymethod` action render a view instead of returning JSON. Then you could just set the `innerHTML` of a div to the ajax response.

Otherwise your approach will work, but you obviously have to delete the existing table rows first:

```
$('#table').tableRemoveRows({from:0, length:???});
```

**Edit**

re-reading your question, it sounds like you're asking more about `setInterval` than actually creating the table. You need to keep re-registering the callback, so something like this:

```
function getdata()
{
    $.getJSON("/mycontroller/mymethod"), function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var row = {  item.ID, item.Date,
                     item.Title
                };
           $(#table).tableInsertRows(row);
        });

        setInterval( getdata, 5000 );

    });
}
setInterval( getdata, 5000 );
```

Comment: When you return a Partial View does only the raw HTML get seen on the AJAX success enabling you to just set the innerHTML?

Comment: I'm asking about both really. I think I get the setInterval but just not sure the best way to get the new data and drawn out to the browser

Comment: @Jon On the server you `return View()` from your `mymethod` action. On the client you'd use `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON` and then just grab the responseText.

Comment: Depending on the volume of data, you may want to consider looking at javascript templating so you can return JSON instead of markup. (MS has a beta version out that I like.)