# Periodically Refresh a partial view ( ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need a periodic refresh of .Net's partial view. It is working with Ajax.ActionLink, is there a similar feature for periodic refresh?  Can I do it without using jQuery?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167116/asp-net-mvc-refresh-table-data-every-5-seconds

Comment: You could put this in the <head> of your html:

<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="10">

Comment: Is it possible to do without js?

Comment: @raym0nd, doesn't that refresh the entire content instead of my partial view?

Answer (score 12):

Zen, you could do it by a code like this:

```
function loadPartialView() {
   $.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")",
    type: 'GET', // <-- make a async request by GET
    dataType: 'html', // <-- to expect an html response
    success: function(result) {
                $('#YourDiv').html(result);
             }
   });
}

$(function() {

   loadPartialView(); // first time

   // re-call the function each 5 seconds
   window.setInterval("loadPartialView()", 5000);

});
```

Remember your Action should return a PartialView.
I hope it helps you!

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE 9 (Didn't bother trying the other IEs), but for now, that is good enough. +1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/16/extending-mvc-auto-refreshing-a-partial-view-using-ajax.aspx) can help you. Which version of MVC are you using? You can set a specified time interval for a helper method. This is the only way I've seen without using js.

Comment: You might have trouble using this method then. But it's the only way that I've seen to perform this without using js, everything else is js related.

Comment: Actually, it's using js but js is just embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")))";
            $("#PartialViewDivId").load(url);
        setInterval(function () {
            var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")))";
            $("#PartialViewDivId").load(url);
        }, 30000); //Refreshes every 30 seconds

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  //Turn off caching
    });
```

It makes an initial call to load the div, and then subsequent calls are on a 30 second interval.

In the controller section you can update the object and pass the object to the partial view.

```
public class ControllerName: Controller
{
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {
        .
        .   // code for update object
        .
        return PartialView("PartialViewName", updatedObject);
    }
}
```